# Open/closed super-string universe surface

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to convert the following figure in tikz:

[image]

The best i have been able to do so far is (...):

```
% Pattern Info
 
\tikzset{
pattern size/.store in=\mcSize, 
pattern size = 5pt,
pattern thickness/.store in=\mcThickness, 
pattern thickness = 0.3pt,
pattern radius/.store in=\mcRadius, 
pattern radius = 1pt}
\makeatletter
\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@pattern@name@_yiqg05m24}{
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\mcThickness,\mcSize]{_yiqg05m24}
{\pgfqpoint{-\mcThickness}{-\mcThickness}}
{\pgfpoint{\mcSize}{\mcSize}}
{\pgfpoint{\mcSize}{\mcSize}}
{
\pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
\pgfsetlinewidth{\mcThickness}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{\mcSize}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}}
\makeatother

% Pattern Info
 
\tikzset{
pattern size/.store in=\mcSize, 
pattern size = 5pt,
pattern thickness/.store in=\mcThickness, 
pattern thickness = 0.3pt,
pattern radius/.store in=\mcRadius, 
pattern radius = 1pt}
\makeatletter
\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@pattern@name@_2kd5sgbgj}{
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\mcThickness,\mcSize]{_2kd5sgbgj}
{\pgfqpoint{-\mcThickness}{-\mcThickness}}
{\pgfpoint{\mcSize}{\mcSize}}
{\pgfpoint{\mcSize}{\mcSize}}
{
\pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
\pgfsetlinewidth{\mcThickness}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{\mcSize}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,592); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 592

%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp8359555790214572] 
\draw  (198,231.2) -- (533.3,231.2)(243.3,37) -- (243.3,275.2) (526.3,226.2) -- (533.3,231.2) -- (526.3,236.2) (238.3,44) -- (243.3,37) -- (248.3,44)  ;
%Straight Lines [id:da309853468854951] 
\draw    (275.3,205.2) -- (141.56,312.75) ;
\draw [shift={(140,314)}, rotate = 321.2] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-4.9) .. controls (6.95,-2.3) and (3.31,-0.67) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.67) and (6.95,2.3) .. (10.93,4.9)   ;
%Shape: Polygon Curved [id:ds8493140407917537] 
\draw  [pattern=_yiqg05m24,pattern size=3.2249999999999996pt,pattern thickness=0.75pt,pattern radius=0pt, pattern color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0}] (255.3,114.2) .. controls (255.3,115.2) and (293.3,127.2) .. (313.44,105.55) .. controls (333.57,83.9) and (363.3,100.2) .. (364.3,102.2) .. controls (365.3,104.2) and (365.3,287.2) .. (367.3,287.2) .. controls (369.3,287.2) and (340.3,267.2) .. (319.3,294.2) .. controls (298.3,321.2) and (254.3,303.2) .. (255.3,303.2) .. controls (256.3,303.2) and (255.3,113.2) .. (255.3,114.2) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Polygon Curved [id:ds2854957461640817] 
\draw  [pattern=_2kd5sgbgj,pattern size=3.2249999999999996pt,pattern thickness=0.75pt,pattern radius=0pt, pattern color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0}] (388.3,118.2) .. controls (388.3,119.2) and (431.3,102.2) .. (446.44,109.55) .. controls (461.57,116.9) and (496.3,104.2) .. (497.3,106.2) .. controls (498.3,108.2) and (498.3,291.2) .. (500.3,291.2) .. controls (502.3,291.2) and (467.3,306.2) .. (452.3,298.2) .. controls (437.3,290.2) and (387.3,307.2) .. (388.3,307.2) .. controls (389.3,307.2) and (388.3,117.2) .. (388.3,118.2) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Polygon Curved [id:ds9662253812544976] 
\draw   (445.3,76.2) .. controls (465.3,77.2) and (529.3,97.2) .. (497.3,106.2) .. controls (465.3,115.2) and (465.3,114.2) .. (446.44,109.55) .. controls (427.57,104.9) and (394.3,114.2) .. (388.3,118.2) .. controls (382.3,122.2) and (378.3,113.2) .. (392.3,100.2) .. controls (406.3,87.2) and (425.3,75.2) .. (445.3,76.2) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (238,17.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$ct$};
% Text Node
\draw (520,212.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x^{2}$};
% Text Node
\draw (136,326.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x^{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (227,212) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {O};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

That leads to... (ignore the grid in the background):

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated to make it look more professional (i will quote you in the textbook).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I use a decoration to define the points along the curve in the horizontal plane; it takes one argument, the number of points.  Then, with those points, the vertical trajectories are drawn using a loop.  The curve is drawn one more time on top of the vertical trajectories.

**Remark** There is a key named `view` that sets the point of view.  I don't like the default one for the 3d drawings.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  view/.style 2 args={%  long, latitude
    z={({-sin(#1)}, {-cos(#1)*sin(#2)})},
    x={({cos(#1)}, {-sin(#1)*sin(#2)})},
    y={(0, {cos(#2)})},
    evaluate={%
      \tox={sin(#1)*cos(#2)};
      \toy={sin(#2)};
      \toz={cos(#1)*cos(#2)};
    }
  },
  strings/.style={% nb of steps
    decoration={%
      markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1/#1 with {
        \tikzmath{%
          {
            \path (0, 0) coordinate[name=P_\pgfkeysvalueof{%
              /pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}];
          };
        }
      }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  },  
}

\tikzmath{%
  integer \N;
  \N = 150;
  real \a;
  \a = 3;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={scale=.8}, view={20}{20}]
  \draw[very thin, ->] (0, 0, 0) -- (\a +3, 0, 0)  node[pos=1.05] {$x^2$};
  \draw[very thin, ->] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, \a +1, 0)  node[pos=1.05] {$ct$};
  \draw[very thin, ->] (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 0, \a +4)  node[pos=1.05] {$x^1$};

  % first drawing
  \draw[strings=\N, canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  (2.5, 2) to[out=90, in=180] ++(1, 2)
  to[out=0, in=180] ++(1, 1)
  to[out=0, in=100] ++(2, -1)
  to[out=-80, in=0] ++(-2, -.5)
  to[out=180, in=-90] cycle;
  \foreach \i [parse=true] in {1, ..., \N+1}{%
    \draw[blue] (P_\i) -- ++(0, 1.5*\a, 0);
  }
  \draw[canvas is xz plane at y={1.5*\a}]
  (2.5, 2) to[out=90, in=180] ++(1, 2)
  to[out=0, in=180] ++(1, 1)
  to[out=0, in=100] ++(2, -1)
  to[out=-80, in=0] ++(-2, -.5)
  to[out=180, in=-90] cycle;  
  \draw[thick, canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  (2.5, 2) ++(1, 2)% to[out=90, in=180] ++(1, 2)
  to[out=0, in=180] ++(1, 1)
  to[out=0, in=100] ++(2, -1);

  % second drawing
   \draw[strings=50, canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  (.5, 5) to[out=0, in=-180] ++(1, -1)
  to[out=0, in=100] ++(1, 1)
  to[out=-80, in=180] ++(1, 1);
  \foreach \i [parse=true] in {1, ..., 51}{%
    \draw[blue!60!black] (P_\i) -- ++(0, 1.5*\a, 0);
  }
   \draw[canvas is xz plane at y={1.5*\a}]
  (.5, 5) to[out=0, in=-180] ++(1, -1)
  to[out=0, in=100] ++(1, 1)
  to[out=-80, in=180] ++(1, 1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow you have a very good level! As i don't master all the stuff you wrote may i ask you to add just the one dimensional string surface next to the bidimensional one as in the original figure i posted?

Thx a lot for your help.